# The tape that connect laptop fan and heatsink

Tags: heatsink, tape

I want to ask about the black tape that connect the fan and heatsink, what is it called? 
It's thin, 20 to 30mm, very adhesive, heat resistant, no elongation, and leave no residue when removed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiEmT.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYBIw.jpg
For larger view click to image

Answer (score 1):

Anti-static and dissipation heat,, sticker (Generaly in silicon because not électrical conducbility).

You Can put KAPTON adhésive 3M by DUPONT or similary. Résistance 200°C and adhésive. Thé black color is for esthetic and for not see that by side out of computer.

The big difficulty is for the same solution...but for the PCB...In any HP computer had a BLACK MASK for a function dissipation heat colling (components PCB), But necessary anti-static and adhésive electrical isolant (silicone glue Composant)

Comment: for PCB face in no-conductibilty electricity

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **Electrical Insulating Tape**. The tape in the picture is probably Vinyl.

Comment: Electrical tape has elongation, but the tape on picture doesn't .

Answer (score 0):

Anti-static and dissipation heat,, sticker (Generaly in silicon because not électrical conducbility).

You Can put KAPTON adhésive 3M by DUPONT or similary. Résistance 200°C and adhésive. Thé black color is for esthetic and for not see that by side out of computer.

The big difficulty is for the same solution...but for the PCB...In any HP computer had a BLACK MASK for a function dissipation heat colling (components PCB), But necessary anti-static and adhésive electrical isolant (silicone glue Composant)

Sée that for you to use in Fan dissipation (but no for PCB !!!)

https://www.google.fr/amp/s/m.aliexpress.com/item/32816049557.html#ampf=undefined